# Trouble setting up sfml/c++ in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, sfml, mingw-w64

I've been trying to set up SFML for graphics for a while and I'm having an issue with running the application. Looked at various tutorials and videos and couldn't find anything, nothing with eclipse that is. After setting up the environment and linking the headers and libraries, the application doesn't open and requires these 3 files:

- libwinpthread-1.dll
- libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll

I've tried a couple things, linking them statically (doesn't seem to work gives the me same error requiring the files), pasting the files into the folder with the other dll files (gives me a error saying  application was unable to start correctly 0xc000007b). The code that is in my main file is from the tutorial page from the sfml website. Here are some properties of my project...

[libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxFGm.png)

[linker settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io9mh.png)

[workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePUkb.png)

[dll's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNPjF.jpg)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2F4P.png)

What am I missing here please help!

Comment: The first one is a pthread implementation for windows. I'm not sure about that one. Never had a problem with it. The second two are bits of the C++ Standard library implementation, and if adding `-static` to c++ Build->Settings-> MinGW C++ Linker->Miscellaneous->Linker Flags Didn't resolve them, All I can suggest is that you make sure you've added `-static` to both the Debug and Release configuration.

Comment: Did you try to put all of the dlls in the same folder as the executable?

Comment: @drescherjm I did add all the dll's, I've added a image in my original post to show the folder and the error it gives me. @user4581301 I've added `-static` to the linker settings and the debug configuration and still gives me the same issue.